# What should I do about my buttons

Tags: java, button, panel

I have a problem about output on Panel. I want to button not over Panel

**My java code**

```
for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++)
{
    if(buttonG[i] == null)
        buttonG[i] = new JButton();
}

int location = 5;

for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
{
    buttonG[i].setText("Group-"+(i+1));
    buttonG[i].setSize(80,50);
    buttonG[i].setLocation(location,10);
    buttonG[i].setVisible(true);

    location = location + 95;
    jPanel1.add(buttonG[i]);

    buttonG[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Output  :

[image]

Comment: You have a fixed X coordinate. Change it.

Comment: please use layout manager.but  y is always same .why.

Comment: You likely want to be using a Layout Manager to handle this (FlowLayout would do what you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
BtnAction action = new BtnAction();
for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
      buttonG[i].addActionListener(action);
}



class BtnAction implement ActionListener{

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         if(e.getActionCommand==enter){
            //enterButtonCode. i assume that you have a btn named enter
        }
      {
}
```

what you're doing is not wrong but there is no point because you cant add write anything inside the actionPerformed method. create a inner class which implements ActionListner and by using addActionListner method pass the object of BtnAction.try doing it in above approach.